# How do I send a message to a UIViewController in a separate file from a custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I'm having a problem trying to set `myButton` enable from another file.

I have a `UIViewController` class with `myButton` and a custom `UIView` class in a separate file. In my `UIView` class I want to change `myButton` enable to true after an animation is done. My `UIViewController` is connected to a `UIViewController` in my `Storyboard`, while the `UIView` is initialized in the `UIViewController` class.

I want to know how can I send a message to my `UIViewController` when the animation is done?

Or how could I access `myButton` in my `UIView` so I can set it to true.

Comment: if the button is in the uiview class, then you can declare the button as a property in uiview class and you can access this property from your uiview controller.

Comment: Yes I know, but I can declare the button in the uiview class due to other things that are happening in the uiview controller. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use delegate method in custom UIView.

Comment: What is your programming language?

Comment: Thanks for guiding me in the right direction. I found this helpful guide that helped me [http://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/]